# Android: what is the mime type to use if I want to see/pick a SQLite database from the Downloads folder?

Tags: android, sqlite, mime-types

I'm writing an application using SQLite database. I already coded for backing up my SQLite database. I now want to be able to restore my application database from such a copy. I am using Android device "Open from" dialog. I see the file if I use other content providers in the list, such as for example "Bluetooth File Transfer"! But I don't see it if I try to use the "Downloads" option.

I copied a SQLite database in my downloads folder. I tried to use fileIntent.setType("*/*").

Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

It's `application/x-sqlite3`. I use this in my own app.

[More info here](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/DB_(SQLite)).

Here's an **example** of how I use it:

```
File backupDB = ...;

//Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(backupDB); //From Android 7, this line results in a FileUriExposedException. Therefore, we must use MyFileProvider instead...
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".com.example.myapp.myfileprovider", backupDB);

Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
newIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-sqlite3");
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(newIntent);
```

For completeness, here is my **MyFileProvider.java** class:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;

public class MyFileProvider extends FileProvider {
}
```

And here's how to declare it in the **manifest**:

```
<provider
    android:name=".MyFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.com.example.myapp.myfileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/my_file_provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

And, finally, here is my **my_file_provider_paths.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**### Update (20th Nov 2019) ###**

Apparently, `application/x-sqlite3` is now deprecated. Please see [Fabian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55071463/1617737), below, for more information.

Comment: Keep in mind that this answer is related to content Type.  The MIME type is different. 

MIME:      application/vnd.sqlite3
Type(s) :  application/x-sqlite3

Answer (score 20):

Since Feb. 2018 the SQLite3 format has an official media type registered at IANA: `application/vnd.sqlite3`. The usage of `application/x-sqlite3` is deprecated and should only be used if backwards-compatibility is required.

See:

- http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Re-Why-is-Sqlite-mediatype-not-registered-at-iana-td97826.html
- https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.sqlite3

Comment: This might help : http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/DB_(SQLite)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a complete answer.  Instead I'll offer a few ideas.

I'm not sure what you mean by the "Open from" dialog.  I'm assuming you mean the "Chooser" dialog, which shows the icons of apps which can handle the intent.

Many Android apps use [MimeTypeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) for associating file extensions and MIME types.  There is no method to iterate over MimeTypeMap to see what all of its mappings are.  I'm fairly confident [these are the mappings](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-4.1.1_r1/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java).  There is no entry in the list for SQLite. A conventional MIME type for SQLite would be "application/x-sqlite3".

In your post, you included `fileIntent.setType("/")`. I'm guessing you actually typed `fileIntent.setType("*/*")`, and because it was not quoted the formatter ate the two stars.

Because you can give any extension you want to your SQLite database files, you have some flexibility in choosing one that produces the results you want.  I'm guessing you want to find something that will not only cause Download to be included in the chooser dialog, but also exclude unwanted apps. You'll probably have to experiment after looking at the list of mappings supported by `MimeTypeMap`.

Comment: Thanks, qbix, for taking the time to look into my question. Yes, I meant star slash star for the MIME type.  And it was the right one to use, I wrote some debugging code to check the SQLite file Mime type and it is effectively the star slash star.

Comment: And the "Open from" dialog is the one that lets you select from "Recent", "Downloads", External SD card, Internal storage, or use from a list of applications. I could only select a file by using some of the listed applications. For example, I could use ES File Explorer, or Dropbox.