# How to filter SQLite3 files using FilePicker in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, filter, mime-types, filepicker

I'm trying to filter files using a FilePicker in Xamarin.Forms. Specifically, SQLite's `.db3` files. In order to filter files in Android, you're supposed to provide the FilePicker MIME types of the files you want to show. This is what I did, based on the MIME types I found SQLite files have:

```cs
var fileTypes = new string[] { "application/x-sqlite3", "application/vnd.sqlite3" };
var file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile(fileTypes);
```

I have also tried putting `"application/db3"`, `"application/db"` inside the `fileTypes` array, but to no avail. **The only time I could filter in SQLite files, and some other ones out, was when I put `"application/*"` in the array, which means the MIME type is of an application.**

These MIME types did not work for me. I have also tried getting MIME types using Xamarin's `Android.Webkit.MimeTypeMap` class like so:

```cs
var MIME =  MimeTypeMap.Singleton;
string sqliteMIME = MIME.GetMimeTypeFromExtension("sqlite");
```

I have tried passing `"sqltie3"`, `"sqltie"`, `"db3"`, `"db"`, `"db0"` to the function call, and the function returned `null` every time.

---

FilePicker's Github repo: https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

Information I found on SQLite's MIME type:

- [Android: what is the mime type to use if I want to see/pick a SQLite database from the Downloads folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301552/android-what-is-the-mime-type-to-use-if-i-want-to-see-pick-a-sqlite-database-fr/55071463#55071463)
- http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/DB_(SQLite)
- https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/vnd.sqlite3

Comment: See if `application/pdf` returns `pdf` (or vice versa) and `text/x-java` returns `java`. If those return from `GetMimeTypeFromExtension`, etc.. correctly, but something common like does not `png` does not return `image/png` (`png` is not included in the base ASOP mime provider), then it sounds like the device is using stock ASOP and NOT providing a mime type supplier via `SetDefaultSupplier` and if so, I like to know you what device are you using 

Comment: I have tried using an emulated Pixel 3a [Android 9.0 - API28], a physical Pixel 3a [Android 11.0 - API30] , and a physical Xiaomi Mi A1 [Android 9.0 - API28]. Except the Xiaomi, everything worked perfectly with `pdf`, `java`, `png` and `csv` file types. The Xiaomi could not filter in the `java` files though.

Comment: @E.Epstein I have check the source code of the MIME type. There is no db mime type. You could refer to the link below. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-cts-6.0_r26/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, I see. So is there no way to filter in SQLite files?

Comment: You could filter with the `FileName`.  Try to filder with `result.FileName.EndsWith("db", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. Please check the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT, I was looking for something to filter the files during the dialog, and not after, but as far as I understand it is impossible for SQLite files. Thank you for all the trouble!

Comment: @E.Epstein I have posted this comment in answer. If this helps you, you could accept as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the source code of the MIME type. There is no db mime type. You could refer to the link below.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-cts-6.0_r26/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java

Answer (score 2):

Try "application/octet-stream".  It works for me.