# How to pick only sqlite db file using intent in android

Tags: android, sqlite

How to set intent type so that it only show .db file. What is the mimetype of sqlite sb. I have tried the solution to this question [Android: what is the mime type to use if I want to see/pick a SQLite database from the Downloads folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301552/android-what-is-the-mime-type-to-use-if-i-want-to-see-pick-a-sqlite-database-fr) but not working.

Currently, I am doing like this:

```
    Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    newIntent.setType("application/vnd.sqlite3");
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivityForResult(newIntent,FILE_PICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
```

But it shows all type of file

Comment: The closest mime type that worked for me is `application/octet-stream`. It still shows some other files, but less than using `*/*` or `application/*`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. 
I've pulled android internal database with all files and it stores sqlite databases without mime type.

[image]

Comment: any alternative way you want to suggest

Comment: No, since setting mime-type is the only way to filter content in the file picker.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**