# FilePicker doesn't accept sqlite database file

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, mime-types

I write a program for Android, which works with Sqlite3 database. I want to pick database file by FilePicker. Database has standard `.db` extension. But the FilePicker does not accept this file.

```
var options = new PickOptions
{
    FileTypes = new FilePickerFileType
    (new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>>
    {
        { DevicePlatform.Android, new[] { "application/vnd.sqlite3", "image/jpeg" } },
        { DevicePlatform.UWP, new[] { ".db" } }
    }),
    PickerTitle = "Please, select database file"
};
```

This options code alloys to accept pictures, but doesn't accept my database file. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Use only `"*/*"`.

Comment: It works, but accepts all the files

Comment: Yes. I hope you understand why.

Comment: I understand and I guess it's fine with me, but for interest, how to accept database files only?

Comment: I have no idea. But now that this works you have time to search in peace for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/android-cts-6.0_r26/luni/src/main/java/libcore/net/MimeUtils.java) of the MIME type, you may find no db mime type supported by android. And use "*/*" will accept all files.

One workaround is to use `application/octet-stream` instead of  `application/vnd.sqlite3`. Though it is the closet mime type, there may be some other files, but much better. More info, please refer to [How to pick only sqlite db file using intent in android.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65211402/how-to-pick-only-sqlite-db-file-using-intent-in-android)

Another way is that we check the file type ourselves, you could check the document here : [Pick file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-picker?tabs=android#pick-file)

```
    var result = await FilePicker.PickAsync();
    if (result != null)
    {
        Text = $"File Name: {result.FileName}";
        if (result.FileName.EndsWith("db", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
             //add your code here
        }
    }
```